# How to make the autocompleter recognize an auto type variable when a statically cast pointer is assigned to it?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

## Details

Recently I have updated to Qt 5.11.2. As part of the release Qt Creator 4.7.1 was installed.

It comes with a real-time code check, which I do not find useful and have removed by unchecking the *ClangCodeModel* under *Help -> Plugins*. This is the only customization I have done to Qt Creator.

## Problem

With this version of Qt Creator I am experiencing the following problem:

When assigning a statically cast pointer to a variable declared as auto, the automatic code completion does not recognize it and I have to type the code manually. The manually typed code is not syntax highlighted as well:

[image]

*The picture is only for showing the syntax highlighting. The code is the same as in the provided example.*

**Note:** the project compiles without errors/warnings, when the code is typed manually.

This worked as expected in the previous versions of Qt Creator I have used.

## Example

Please, consider the following minimal example I have written in order to reproduce the problem:

*main.cpp*

```
class A {
public:
    A::A() {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() {
    }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv[]*/)
{
    A *a = new B();
    auto *b = static_cast<B *>(a);

    static_cast<B *>(a)->foo(); // "->foo();" is autocompleted
    b->foo();                   // Need to type "->foo();" manually

    return 0;
}
```

How to make the autocompleter/syntax highlighter work?

Comment: the problem is with the IDE [tag:qt-creator], it's not with [tag:qt]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I agree

Comment: @eyllanesc, still, wouldn't be a good idea to bring it to the attention of the Qt users (you know, because of the watched tags), since they most probably will have the same problem or even better - know a solution.

Comment: okay, I was also thinking, I think the [tag:qt] is correct but not [tag:qt5]

Comment: @eyllanesc, again: I agree. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order the code recognition and completion to work correctly, Qt Creator 4.7.1 based on Qt 5.11.2 needs the Clang Code Model:

*Help* -> *Installed Plugins* -> *ClangCodeModel*

This, however, turns the line annotations on. If this is not desired, they could be turned off by going to

*Tools* -> *Options* -> *Text Editor* -> *Display*

and unchecking *Line annotations*.